# How to do variable substitution in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I've got a bit of complex sql code that I'm converting from MSSql to Postgres (using Entity Framework Core 2.1), to deal with potential race conditions when inserting to a table with a unique index. Here's the dumbed-down version:

```
const string QUERY = @"
DO
$$
    BEGIN
        insert into Foo (Field1,Field2,Field3)
        values (@value1,@value2,@value3);
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        -- do nothing; it's a race condition
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select *
from Foo
where Field1 = @value1
and Field2 = @value2;
";

return DbContext.Foos
                .FromSql(QUERY,
                    new NpgsqlParameter("value1", value1),
                    new NpgsqlParameter("value2", value2),
                    new NpgsqlParameter("value3", value3))
                .First();
```

In other words, try to insert the record, but don't throw an exception if the attempt to insert it results in a unique index violation (index is on Field1+Field2), and return the record, whether it was created by me or another thread.

This concept worked fine in MSSql, using a `TRY..CATCH` block. As far as I can tell, the way to handle Postgres exceptions is as I've done, in a plpgsql block.

**BUT...**

It appears that variable substitution in plpgsql blocks doesn't work. The code above fails on the `.First()` (no elements in sequence), and when I comment out the `EXCEPTION` line, I see the real problem, which is:

> Npgsql.PostgresException : 42703: column "value1" does not exist

When I test using regular Sql, i.e. doing the `insert` without using a plpgsql block, this works fine.

So, what is the correct way to do variable substitution in a plpgsql block?

Comment: Thanks for the very good question. I learned something new today trying to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the body of the `DO` statement is actually a string, a text. [See reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html#id-1.9.3.98.7)

`$$`  is just another way to delimit text in postgresql. It can be just as well be replaced with `'` or `$somestuff$`.

As it is a string, Npgsql and Postgresql have no reason to mess with `@value1` in it.

**Solutions**? Only a very ugly one, so not using this construction, as you're not able to pass it any values. And messing with string concatenation is no different than doing concatenation in C# in the first place.

**Alternatives**? [Yes!](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

You don't need to handle exceptions in plpgsql  blocks. Simply insert, use the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, and be on your way.

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES (@value1,@value2,@value3)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

select *
from Foo
where Field1 = @value1
and Field2 = @value2;
```

**Or if you *really* want to  keep using plpgsql**, you can simply [create a temporary table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TEMPORARY), using the `ON COMMIT DROP` option, fill it up with these parameters as one row, then use it in the `DO` statement. For that to work all your code must execute as part of [one transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html). You can use one explicitly just in case.

The only ways to pass parameters to plpgsql code is via these 2 methods:

1. Declaring a function, then calling it with arguments
2. When already inside a plpgsql block  you can call:
   `EXECUTE $$ INSERT ... VALUES ($1, $2, $3); $$ USING 3, 'text value', 5.234;`

*End notes:*
*As a  fellow T-SQL developer who loved its freedom, but transitioned to Postgresql, I have to say that the BIG difference is that on one side there's T-SQL which gives the power, and on the other side it's a very powerful Postgresql-flavored SQL. plpgsql is very rarely warranted. In fact, in a code base of megabytes of complex SQL stuff, I can rewrite pretty much every plpgsql code in SQL. That's how powerful it really is compared to MSSQL-flavored SQL. It just takes some getting used to, and befriending the very ample documentation. Good luck!*

Comment: Brilliant! From now on my rule of thumb is going to be "find the SQL alternative to plpgsql".